# Триггерийная функция PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

У меня есть триггер-функция, которая должна дополнять запрос:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 2);
```

Мне нужно перед выполнением данного запроса произвести его модификацию и добавить еще одну колонку со значением, которое я получу из другой таблицы. В теле функции я пробовал использовать:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_fnc()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN    
NEW.col3 := (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE col1 = NEW.col2); -- Проблема тут
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER update_table2
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON table
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fnc();
```

При выполнении функции в col3 падает значение null:

```
INSERT INTO table (cpl1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 2, null);
```

Но если выполнять этот же селект вне функции, то проблем не возникает и возвращается нужное мне значение.

Несколько часов поиска ответа в сети так и не привели меня к какому-то положительному результату и вынужден просить помощи у вас. Возможно, я не правильно присваиваю значение или есть какой-то метод который упускаю.

Пример таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE table(
  id int,
  col1 int,
  col2 int,
  col3 int
);

CREATE TABLE table2(
  id int,
  col1 int,
);
```

Comment: Выложите минимальный пример (см. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) пункты 5 и 3).

Comment: @Akina ну если так будет проще...

Comment: Не вижу проблемы. Если присваивается NULL - значит, в таблице table2 тупо нет записи с нужным значением. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JjjPc8s3) (первая таблица переименована в table1 для устранения ошибки синтаксиса). PS. Я предпочитаю всё же синтаксис SELECT INTO: `SELECT id INTO NEW.col3 FROM table2 WHERE col1 = NEW.col2;`, как по мне, он более очевиден и прозрачен.

Comment: Все еще не понимаю почему возвращался нулл, но когда вывел отдельно  `SELECT id INTO id_row FROM ...` а потом положил `id_row` в `NEW.col3` проблема ушла. Что касается отсутствия данных во второй таблице, то они есть, т.к. отдельно выполнял селект с нужными параметрами и значение возвращалось.

Проблему решил сам, но вопрос пока оставлю открытым пока +/- не будет понятно почему так происходило.